# How can I change text to number in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, numbers

Here is what I put in the cell

="A "&'2018-2019'!C34&" B"

and this is what I got

A 1256838 B

But I want it to display like this

A 1,256,838 B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXT to format the number.

```
="A "&TEXT('2018-2019'!C34, "#,##0")&" B"
```

In fact, if the prefix and suffix characters are static, they can be wrapped into the format mask.

```
 =TEXT('2018-2019'!C34, "\A #,##0 \B")
```

The `\` is an escape character. I'm pretty sure that A is not a reserved character in a format mask but B is used for the Buddhist calendar.

Comment: for this case A and B is literally just a word

Comment: Yes. The `\\` allows you to use A and B without them being converted while the #,##0 is used to convert the number to the correct format. These are called 'string literals'.